# Parent to child theme- Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child

I have already started working on a wordpress theme and need to make it a child theme to prevent updates from changing my site and customisation.

Is there any wat that I could do this?

Comment: You might be better served by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow these 3 steps:

**1) Create a folder for your theme in /wp-content/themes/:**

"It is recommended (though not required, especially if you're creating a theme for public use) that the name of your child theme directory is appended with '-child'.".

Every file you create here will overwrite files in your parent theme. You can, for instance, create new Page templates: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ or overwrite the existing ones.

**2) Create am a style.css file and begin it with:**

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

Add here your custom styles. More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

**3) Create a functions.php**

Inside this file, you can add new functionality your child theme or modify the existing one.

You will also have to enqueue here the CSS and JS of your parent theme, as well as the new CSS and JS that you create on your child theme. Something like that will do the most of the times:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Now you can add custom shortcodes (https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) , widgets areas (https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes), etc..

More documentation about child themes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes